# Loading issue on Google Place Autocomplete API Html

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have use Google MAP Place Autocomplete API for web.

[For code and output click here.](https://jsfiddle.net/sz6vhj38/3/)

```
<form>
   <input id="origin-input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From"/> <br/>              
   <input id="destination-input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To"/> <br/>

   <div>
      <button id="NOW" onclick="selectDateTime(this.id)">NOW</button>
      <button id="LATER" onclick="selectDateTime(this.id)">LATER</button>
   </div> <br/>       
   <div id="now_later" > </div>

   <button onclick="handleMap()">SUBMIT</button>

   <script>
      function selectDateTime(elemId){
         var html = '';
         if (elemId == "NOW") {
            html += '<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="within_now">';
            html += '<div class="btn-group" >';
            html += '15 Min <input type="radio" name="within_min" id="within_min" value="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            html += '30 Min <input type="radio" name="within_min" id="within_min" value="30">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            html += '45 Min <input type="radio" name="within_min" id="within_min" value="45" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';                               
         }

         document.getElementById("now_later").innerHTML = html;
      }
      </script>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="map" class="service col-sm-4"></div>
    <script>             
        function initMap()                     
           var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
           origin_input.value = '';
           var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');
           destination_input.value = '';

           /* Set autocomplete on textboxes */
           var autocompleteOrigin;
           var autocompleteDest;
           var map = null;
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                 center: {lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629}, zoom: 8});
           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

           // HTML5 geolocation. (Loads when page 1st loads - marks your current location on map)
           if (navigator.geolocation) {
                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                        var pos = {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude
                        };

                        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
                        map.setCenter(pos);
                    }, function() {
                        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                    });
                } else {
                    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                }

               /*Set autocomplete on textboxes*/
                autocompleteOrigin = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
                autocompleteDest = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);

                 /*Set directionService*/
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


                // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

                var travel_mode = 'DRIVING';

                /* add bounds to map */
                autocompleteOrigin.bindTo('bounds', map);
                autocompleteDest.bindTo('bounds', map);

                function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(17);
                    }
                }

                var origin_place_id = null, destination_place_id = null;

                // set place_changed listner on autocomplete text boxes
                autocompleteOrigin.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                    var place = autocompleteOrigin.getPlace();
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                        return;
                    }

                    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

                    // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
                    // the other place ID
                    origin_place_id = place.place_id;
                    route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
                });

                autocompleteDest.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                    var place = autocompleteDest.getPlace();
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                        return;
                    }
                    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

                    // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
                    // the other place ID
                    destination_place_id = place.place_id;
                    route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
                });
```

The problems I'm facing are:

1) **If i press enter while selecting autocomplete the entire page loads , However if i use mouse to select autocomplete option page doesn't load.**

2) **On clicking the NOW button, the entire page loads instead of just updating  *div now_later***

3) **On clicking submit button entire page loads again**

I don't want my page to be loaded on clicking any button or updating autocomplete.
I'm facing this issue because of autocomplete place API.
My ultimate aim is to plot the route between source and destination once user enters source and destination. Then if user clicks on Now a div should expand.
Further when user clicks on submit, map will be updated with other stuff.

Please help me. Tell me where I go wrong and how to rectify it. Even if you can solve one issue that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()` in your action listeners

Comment: @elsololobo exactly where to add e.preventDefault()?

Comment: You could simply overcome your issue, by just replacing the `<form>` with a did, and perform the action with pure JavaScript. If you don´t want to do this, as mentioned in my first comment **in your action listeners**

Comment: thanks a lot @elsololobo ..... replacing <form> with<div> worked. But why did <form> fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replacing `<form>` tag with `<div>` tag will solve the loading problem and also allow to use enter key for selection of option in autocomplete.